# Infinite repeating pattern in regex

Tags: regex

I am having some difficult in figuring out how to enforce a repeating pattern as a condition in regex.

Following is an example demonstrating the problem :

```
$path = '/foo/../../bar/../something/../results/in/skipthis/../this/';
$vpath = preg_replace('/(.*\/\.\.\/)/', '/', $path );
```

The above regex matches `/foo/../../bar/../something/../results/in/skipthis/../` because it sees `/foo/../../bar/../something/../results/in/skipthis/` as the `.*\/` portion of the condition, however it should match the following list :

```
foo/../
../../
bar/../
something/../
skipthis/../
```

And do the replace on them accordingly.  Note there is no forward slash in the results I expect to see, and that it is a list of ALL the results -- not a wide single result starting at the beginning of the first found match and ending at the end of the last part of the found match.

The above list is what I expect to match -- however... the regex must allow for infinite `.*/../` matches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe I resolved this ---  `([\w\d\s\ \-\.]+?)\/\.\.\/`

Comment: Add your own answer and mark it as the correct one so that others can see what the solution is =)

Comment: It is very close ... it doesn't seem to match  ../../ though .  I need to figure some way so it matches everything.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Expected result is no matter how many path-ups are in the string, that it collapses accordingly.  Aka, it should function the same way `realpath` in php does, except without requiring the path to physically exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[^/]*` instead of `.*` in the match.  It might be `[!/]*` rather than `[^/]*`.

Here's an example using sed:

```
sed 's,[^/]*/\.\./,/,g'
foo/../
/
../../
/
bar/../
/
something/../
/
skipthis/../
/
```

Note every-other-line is input and the rest are output.

Comment: could you share full example please ? .. if you look at my comment, you will not i no longer use *